# Reading each line of a text file into VB

Tags: text, excel, output, worksheet-function, vba

I'm looking to automate some work that I currently have to carry out. 
I currently receive a number of machine names that I have to query in unix from config files, but I have to amend the list I receive each day to produce the command. I'm looking for a way to automate this, so I can store the names in a text file and run a script in vb that will automatically produce the command I need to run in unix.

e.g the text file (machines.text) may contain the following:

ABCDE1234
ADEFR1234
BCDFREWE1

each line will be the machine name, but i require this to be changed to lower case and get the following commands output:

```
grep -i abcdef1234 */*.cfg
grep -i adefr1234 */*.cfg 
grep -i bcdfrewe1 */*.cfg
```

I sometimes get hundreds a day, so looking to shorten the processes as I can just use the original file i receive and not have to manually go through it.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, even if anyone has any alternatives to VB and excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could open the list in Excel, so that all the data to be manipulated goes into Column A, then use formulas as below to create your UNIX commands in Columns B, C, D:

**FIRST Command**:

```
="grep -i " &LOWER(LEFT(A:A,FIND(" ",A:A)))  & " */*.cfg"
```

**SECOND Command**:

```
="grep -i "&LOWER(LEFT(TRIM(MID(A:A,FIND(" ",A:A),LEN(A:A))),FIND(" ",TRIM(MID(A:A,FIND(" ",A:A),LEN(A:A))))))&" */*.cfg"
```

**THIRD Command**:

```
="grep -i "&LOWER(MID(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND(" ",A:A)),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND(" ",A:A))),LEN(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-FIND(" ",A:A)))))&" */*.cfg"
```

Once you have got all your texdt to be manipulated in Column A, copy down the formulas in columns B,C,D

[image: Below is a screenshot showing the three result commands]
then you could run the below code (may need tweaking) to create your output:

```
Sub getCommands()

Dim oFso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim oWriteFile As TextStream

Dim oRange As Range

Set oWriteFile = oFso.CreateTextFile("C:\Commands.txt", True)

Set oRange = Range("B2")

Do Until oRange.Text = ""

    With oWriteFile
        .WriteLine oRange.Text
        .WriteLine oRange.Offset(0, 1).Text ' second command
        .WriteLine oRange.Offset(0, 2).Text ' third command
    End With
    Set oRange = oRange.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
oWriteFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: @user2527648: GREAT, in that case please mark my answer using the Check mark below the up/down vote arrows on the left